# Encoding error when saving webpage to text file

Tags: python-3.x, encoding

```
from selenium import webdriver
import requests

linkElems = 0
browser = webdriver.Edge \
(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\edgedriver_win64\msedgedriver.exe')
lists = [r'http://rockfordcityil.iqm2.com/Citizens/calendar.aspx']
             
def rockford(lists):
    browser.get(lists[0])
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#ContentPlaceholder1_pnlMeetings \
    > div:nth-child(5) > div.RowTop > div.RowLink > a').click()
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#ContentPlaceholder1_hlPublicAgendaFile').click()
    switch_windows(browser.current_url)
    write_file(browser.current_url, 'Rockford.txt')

def switch_windows(url):
    original_window = browser.current_window_handle
    for window_handle in browser.window_handles:
        if window_handle != original_window:
            browser.switch_to_window(window_handle)
            
            
def write_file(url,fileName):
   res = requests.get(url)
   playFile = open(fileName , 'wb')
   for chunk in res.iter_content(100000):
       playFile.write(chunk)
```

rockford(lists)

The code is executing correctly however when I open the text file in my working directory the file is unreadable. Below is a snippet from how it opens.

```
%PDF-1.5
%µµµµ
1 0 obj
<</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R/Lang(en-US) /StructTreeRoot 36 0 R/MarkInfo<</Marked true>>>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<</Type/Pages/Count 8/Kids[ 3 0 R 21 0 R 23 0 R 25 0 R 27 0 R 29 0 R 31 0 R 33 0 R] >>
endobj
3 0 obj
<</Type/Page/Parent 2 0 R/Resources<</Font<</F1 5 0 R/F2 9 0 R/F3 11 0 R/F4 13 0 R/F5 15 0 R/F6 19 0 R>>/ExtGState<</GS7 7 0 R/GS8 8 0 R>>/XObject<</Image17 17 0 R>>/ProcSet[/PDF/Text/ImageB/ImageC/ImageI] >>/Annots[ 18 0 R] /MediaBox[ 0 0 612 792] /Contents 4 0 R/Group<</Type/Group/S/Transparency/CS/DeviceRGB>>/Tabs/S/StructParents 0>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<</Filter/FlateDecode/Length 3083>>
stream
xœÅ]Sã¶öþƒÞêt@±$ît:“
»]v–…ÜöaÛ;‰‡ÄNmJúÛï9Gv ‰
Mw™ÁØ–¬óý¡£CPTé8Uì§ŸúƒªŠFÓ$fßú×ùâþõÃ"é_D“4‹ª4ÏúWË›
_}J¢8)~þ™½?²?lnãO($³™W?”¬H~û‘e‡ï¯ú.=v=><0Ïf‚ù’ÛÒa¾#8ü¹žÃ¼_®|6)aM6¡§ ~úåðà›Åz°ëÏ‡`Åÿ¼´tC®ü§  b
h˜V½c!­‡žp-6ìûV¾ì++¥3sH(WrßíBbgjwÃF¶ŠBzÜ    ^Jé+îû]Pþé9 éXkÐ“Òš$½cie±!ØJ—Ã.ØJ—ý³,ÉÂuP*àN'™{2S±€ÛÎØ©‚.8 ¶®•V¬'ë8›õ\ë^ëªwìXI”|„lÎ{¾•ÁoÌð«p7Ë{!½.Œáëz‚‡æ”ìuÈ(ùÂãò-¤lÛîÛÃqüô\æ=ak1ßö<k: åêZñÉûô<32¼x8U n¼³ñâ˜Ó×åŽ9æïd§­Z`+îÈ·óyu¤i‡r™L–³eP°³™O—*Í&ûú¢më0c”Î6-ô|"ëpð}1iî.    â”­"*ñ²x×Gõìßƒ÷¿‡üåE­£íJ›Îø$ïÖ<ô
z§ ñ~ýÿ¿†z¡B‹ùþ¦â62•F›¦¢€N·ÊYO
8¦+ÆèÁÍæfGì3¨Y.ñ‹æÀôqž%áÎ†_‰£ÂÆÊ¸çãË«PñxàR
Zø¦xÅmÑÅÞ¾sÐ^ñŽ]àÝÙ~å“!—Ê0…-Jî
Ÿ{æ8ùz‹s=îÁƒ}8²~Ç~ï}^Uù¼{Ë÷1Ï«·|îFZ\ï1¤MtnôK&œ¡¡&h¹”®V  Ù9Óéˆ¦ëY}ÕCûÅ;  w¶¶m_ß0%4H—w=¡,…wÁjt°§RÊMs¡à~ÐAŽq   í¶#gš'lå¶ àha éðl»‰^W‚¦p~:&‰ðÙIÎ´Xÿ:žž0{G=Øâ\­ž£ÐÖ6Yw=M@®lœÏfù=æA!j@h   HyQ4*R&²ª¤úK36” ¡ ³k-‚}Ì£<cšèíeI…cM‹<ËaØåà†s‚š‘Ž0˜`à˜±¼ˆ‹‚åoÌ ®gå#Œ¸þÆi¦¿-Y+UOÁQe©ˆ  DI{ÕÁ:I    Ë–¶rË)LgˆNˆ”ÏçøƒªJ'™šÌ9õS•R}ƒQ¾cÃ&†ÎhVåì¼€©1ñUGÔS´®ì.ox­–É³# ÀÞ$ž a³|ÌÀO½Z‚‹k–GÈrÂ7¡HM_-of´¾fW”$&õú·
ÓñkÓL…‰½ÍT›Å-"ÝÛ¤–P'=qé’¢Bº‹¸]TlðjË¨…)£¶%—»ƒ—†À»AÐ–*·ª9›6Žb³;@°ß+¿ÁË_8‰·
```

Comment: Welcome To SO.  This looks more like a PDF file than a text file.

Comment: @Mike, did my answer help you resolve your problem? if so, please mark it as accepted to indicate that, by clicking the V to its left. If not, please let me know and I'll try to further help.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to save a `pdf` file, not a `txt` file, so change this:

```
write_file(browser.current_url, 'Rockford.txt')
```

into this:

```
write_file(browser.current_url, 'Rockford.pdf')
```

Comment: Thank you that fixed it!

Comment: @Mike, glad it helped. Please mark my answer as accepted by clicking the V symbol to the left of my answer.